# How to configure serverless framework HttpApi Authorizer for custom lambda authorizer

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

In the documentation there is information on how to configure authorizers such as Cognito:

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api#jwt-authorizers

And here is a copy of it:

```
  httpApi:
    authorizers:
      someJwtAuthorizer:
        identitySource: $request.header.Authorization
        issuerUrl: https://cognito-idp.${region}.amazonaws.com/${cognitoPoolId}
```

Does anyone know how to configure for custom lambda jwt authorizer I have coded myself?

Comment: At the time of writing this comment, this is not possible with serverless framework although AWS supports this.

Answer (score 0):

I only achieved it using a previously created JWT Authorizer for httpApi, but must be similar with a custom Lambda Authorizer (never used one)

```
      - httpApi:
          method: any
          authorizer: # https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/7598
            # Provide both type and authorizerId
            type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS # TOKEN or REQUEST or COGNITO_USER_POOLS, same as AWS Cloudformation documentation
            id: <AUTHORIZER ID>  # or authorizer name "name: my-lambda"
            scopes: # Optional - List of Oauth2 scopes when type is COGNITO_USER_POOLS
              - my-resource-server/my-grant-type
          path: /{proxy+}
```

More on this issue here:

[AWS HTTP API: Support IAM and Lambda authorizers #8210](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/8210)

[feat(AWS HTTP API): Add support for custom Lambda authorizers #9192](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/9192)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Serverless Plugins Configuration]

[image: Serverless Function Authorizers]

This configurations work today.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: @starball The use of images as comments is not prohibited, Stackoverflow makes a recommendation to avoid the use of images to help screen readers, search engines and code indexing to work with the comment, in my answer I have attached images because the solution that I offer is not related to a complex structure but to the suggestion of my current project, which I do not want to be indexed for example.

Comment: images in comments? You used an image in an answer post. an answer post is not a comment.